# Settar value in backend after setValue in frontend

Tags: javascript, php, extjs

I have the following code:

```
selectMainSector: function(component) {
    var typeSectorId = component.getValue(), mainCombobox = component.nextSibling();
    if (typeSectorId == 0) { //se o valor for 0 - setor
        mainCombobox.disable();
        mainCombobox.setValue('');
    }
    if (typeSectorId != 0) { //Se o valor for 1 - subsetor
        mainCombobox.enable();
    }
},
```

In this code I make a rule for when combobox is selected, it enables the next one and when it selects the other record it hides combobox again and clears the value. But if I edit the registry and select the value that hides and clears the other saved combobox, the value is still sent and saved. I think when I'm giving setValue, I'm not clearing the value that was saved before, so it still saves. But it only 
lears the field in the frontend, as I can also clear the value that goes to the backend.

[image]

Comment: The front end and back end don't automatically talk to one another. YOU need to force communication by submitting the form or using ajax.

Comment: Exactly, how do I do to force communication by submitting?

Comment: You either submit the form or you use ajax.

Comment: What is the code for your form? More information goes a long way in others being able to provide good answers.